# CSS - Add border to all divs

Tags: css, html

I was wondering if there was any "easy" way to add through css lets say:

`border: 1px solid red;`

to all divs no matter what their id´s are.

I realize this might be a very very basic question (or no possible at all) and I hope it is clear enough.

Just to clarify, lets say I´ve got:

HTML

```
<div id="one">

</div>

<div id="two">

</div>
```

and CSS

```
#one{
height: 10px;
width: 10px;
}

#two{
height: 10px;
width: 10px;
}
```

The result I actually want is:

```
#one{

height: 10px;
width: 10px;
border: 1px solid red;
}

#two{
height: 10px;
width: 10px;
border: 1px solid red;
}
```

I want to achieve this without having to go one by one.

Thanks in advance!!

Please ask for any clarification needed!

Comment: I'd suggest reading around the basics of how CSS works, perhaps starting with this [W3-hosted article, by Dave Raggett](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/Guide/Style).

Comment: Now that I see it was quite a stupid question :)  I just was blocked!! thanks to all

Comment: Opera has a [free online course on HTML and CSS](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/1-introduction-to-the-web-standards-cur/). It's really comprehensive and goes at a relaxed pace. Plenty of examples too.

Comment: my point wasn't (at all) to make you feel stupid for asking a question (the *point* of Stackoverflow is, after all, to become the go-to repository for software/programming/scripting Q&A), it was just a nudge towards reading up on the basics. I'm sorry if I caused any offence, it wasn't my intent.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
div {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

Comment: I cant believe I could no see that coming, thank you very much. sorry for the dumb question, thank you very much

Comment: Not a stupid question at all, merely not fully understanding how css works.  I would recommend using a class though if this is intended to be useful.  most pages have so many div objects adding a border to each would be pretty crazy.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @McAden's answer.
Alternatively, you can use jquery to add the style on the fly:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('div').css('border','1px solid #000');
</script>
```

Comment: The down-voter really *should* have explained their down-vote, but I'd hazard a guess that it's to do with over-complicating things. What you say is *true*, but over-kill for the particular situation.

Answer (score 2):

As McAden was saying, you may want to specify which divs you want to style. Instead of adding a class to each div you may want to try an approach like this,

```
.theseDivs div{
    /*styles here*/
}

<div class="theseDivs">
    <div>Style applied here</div>
    <div>and here, </div>
</div>
<div>but not here</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For all elements

```
<style> * {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help you:

```
div#one, div#two{
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Not quite what he asked, but it's good to teach him the comma syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
CSS Using
#one{
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
border:1px solid #000;
}
// you can use sepertely
#two{
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
border-top: 1px solid #000;
border-left: 1px solid #000;
border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
```

JQuery Using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#one').css('border','1px solid #000');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('div').css("border", "1px solid #CCC");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
1
  <div>
    3
    </div>
<div>
2
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Plain JavaScript:

```js
const style = document.createElement('style');
style.innerHTML= "div {border: 1px solid #FF0000 !important};";
document.head.appendChild(style);
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.